# Ruby: Optimizing storage for holding a huge number of strings, some of them duplicates

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have a text file with two columns. The values in the first column ("key") are all different, the values in the second column - these strings have a length between 10 and approximately 200 - have some duplicates. The number of duplicates varies. Some strings - especially the longer ones - don't have any duplicate, while others might have 20 duplicate occurancies.

```
key1  valueX
key2  valueY
key3  valueX
key4  valueZ
```

I would like to represent this data as a hash. Because of the large number of keys and the existence of duplicate values, I am wondering, whether some method of sharing common strings would be helpful.

The data in the file is kind of "constant", i.e. I can put effort (in time of space) to preprocess it in a suitable way, as long as it is accessed efficiently, once it is entered my application.

I will now outline an algorithm, where I believe this would solve the problem. **My question is**, whether the algorithm is sound, respectively whether it could be improved. Also, I would like to know whether using `freeze` on the strings would provide an additional optimization:

In a separated **preprocessing process**, I find out which strings values are indeed duplicate, and I annotate the data accordingly (i.e. create a third column in the file), in that all occurances of a repeated string except the first occurance, have a pointer to the first occurance:

```
key1  valueX
key2  valueY
key3  valueX  key1
key4  valueZ
```

When I read **in my application** the data into memory (line by line), I use this annotation, to create a pointer to the original string, instead of allocating a new one:

```
if columns.size == 3
  myHash[columns[0]] = columns[1] # First occurance of the string
else
  myHash[columns[0]] = myHash[columns[2]].dup # Subsequent occurances
end
```

Will this achieve my goal? Can it be done any better?

Comment: Why do you think this achieves your goal? you create a duplicate of the duplicated value - which means you hold it twice in memory... it seems like this is an extreme overkill - do you have a real problem, or are you optimizing pre-maturely?

Comment: Your question seems to be, "I am wondering, whether some method of sharing common strings would be helpful." We are not given your "goal". If we were, we would not have the criteria to determine whether it has been achieved (unless that's subjective, a no--no for SO questions).

Comment: @UriAgassi: It's `dup`, not `clone`. This makes sure, that only one copy of the string is present. And, given the huge amount of strings, I don't think it is pre-maturely, but aside from this, I am also interested in the problem itself.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I think I don't fully understand your comment, so let me clarify: The goal is saving heap memory. In a naive implementation, identical strings would be stored in different copies. I am searching a way to reduce the memory needed. The simplest would be to use (in my example) 'myHash[columns[0]] = myHash[columns[2]]' - this also shares already -, but I read an article about Ruby memory management, which explains how using `dup` saves even more. I hope to cut down the memory footprint from a few GB to maybe half a GB - just to give you an idea.

Comment: I'm not sure you meant [`dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-dup)... perhaps you meant [`intern`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-intern)?

Comment: 1) Don't store GB of data in RAM. That's what databases and key/value stores are for. 2) De-duplication is a complex topic. Consider SQL normal forms, lrzip, or other [data de-duplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_deduplication) mechanisms, rather than trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @CodeGnome: We do have a DB, but the access of a data item takes longer in a DB. I also investigate in a caching scheme, where I can fetch that part of the data from the DB into memory, which will be needed for execution, but this still might be a quite large amount.

Comment: @UriAgassi: I really meant `dup`, based on [this](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/1/18/seeing-double-how-ruby-shares-string-values) article, but on second thought, `dup` doesn't seem to bring any advantage here, since I am not going to modify the strings in any way.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is using symbols.

```
["a", "b", "c", "a", "d", "c"].each do |c|
  puts c.intern.object_id
end

417768 #a
313128 #b
312328 #c
417768 #a
433128 #d
312328 #c
```

Note how c got the same value.

You can turn a string into a symbol with the `intern` method. If you intern an equal string you should get the same symbol out, like a [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

If you save the symbol in your hash you'll just have each string a single time. When it's time to use the symbol just call `.to_s` on the symbol and you'll get the string back. (Not sure how the to_s works, it may do creation work on each call.) Another idea would be to cache strings your self, ie have an integer to string cache hash and just put the integer key in your data structures. When you need the string you can look it up.

Comment: As for `intern`: @UriAgassi also suggested this in his comment. I will investigate this. It is correct, that `to_s` recreates the string, but this is only one string at a time (during processing), and the memory is reclaimed afterwards. Also, not all of the strings are really "used" for comparision during each run.

Comment: Using an integer key is conceptionally a good idea, but perhaps not necessary, if I store the object reference to the string. Perhaps I was mislead into using `dup` (see my other comments to this topic), and just "reassigning the existing string" would exactly achieve my goal.